# Mac Pro 2013 A1481 Power Supply Test

Tags: power, mac-pro, logicboard

I have a Mac Pro 2013 A1481 with a suspected bad power supply, I would like to test the bus bars from the PSU to the logic board with a multimeter. Would anyone be able to provide some instructions on where to place the black (ground) probe and red probe? and what the proper voltage readings should be? Please refer to the attached photo with numbers. Much appreciated
[image]

Comment: I don't know which terminals, but the issue here is not just knowing which to test, but having it under the correct load as you measure. Measuring an unloaded power supply will give very misleading figures.

Comment: Right, however the machine is not booting. I am trying to determine if the issue is with the PSU or the logic board so I can get the right part to replace.

Comment: You still can only measure output voltage under load. If you don't have a meter that can simulate load, you need to give it to a professional who does. tbh, you can probe between any points & see what they read, you won't hurt anything if you're voltage testing, the resistance is like 10 million ohms…. but the answer won't tell you anything.

Comment: I see Tetsujin, honestly if not for the current mess we are in (all Apple repair centers closed around me), I wouldn't typically try this on my own. But in a bind I need to learn to diag on my own for now. So if I place the positive probe on one of these bars and the ground probe on a screw point on the board with the machine plugged in, it wouldn't hurt anything? But the result won't tell me anything...hmm

Comment: idk the exact physics/electronics behind this, but PSUs get 'tired' over time & fail to push the full correct voltage. The trouble is that they're perfectly capable of pushing 12v, for instance, when not under load, so your meter will read 12v. Once under load, then it might only be managing 8 or 10v & fail to power the device. I used to have a job where a good deal of time was spent replacing failing 'tired' PSUs. We had a simple red/orange/green LED device which would correctly simulate the proper equipment load, precisely because of this issue.

Comment: I tested the voltage output from the PSU bus bars, got readings of 0's everywhere, pretty sure PSU is shot. Going to replace it next,